# How to make child folder as separate branch and upload it to github?

Tags: git, github

I have some question about git and github.

I have a root folder "project" which contains two folders.
./project/complete 
./project/starter

And usually I upload my child folders as master branch to github.
But also I want to create new branch which contains the only "complete" folder as a root folder of this branch and push it as separate branch of my repository.
How could I achieve this result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Git never stores folders: it stores only *files* (in commits; the repository itself then stores these commits).  You can choose to have Git store files named `project/complete/file1` and `project/starter/file2`, for instance.  When checking out a commit that contains files with these names, Git will make a folder named `project` as your OS requires, then, within `project`, make a folder named `complete` as your OS requires, and another folder named `starter` as your OS requires.  Git is now able to extract the files named `project/complete/file1` and `project/starter/file2`.

You can, however, make one Git *repository* within `project/complete`, and have it store commits that store a file named `file1`, and make a *different* Git repository within `project/starter`, and have that second Git project store commits that store a file named `file2`.  You then have *two separate repositories*, with distinct and separate commits.  You will need to make your own `project` and then `project/complete` folders, enter the second folder, and clone the first repository and have it extract the file `file1`.

Within this model—of a repository containing commits—we add *branch names* as entities within each repository.  A branch name just holds the raw hash ID of a single commit.  Checking out a "branch" means *extract, from the repository, the one specific commit identified by the branch name*.  Git will extract *all* the files from this commit—with whatever file names they have—in the usual manner, creating OS-level folders if needed.

What all this means is that this claim:

> And usually I upload my child folders as master branch to github.

needs some kind of fancy interpretation.  My best guess is that what you really mean is "I make a new, empty Git repository, create a new commit, and assign the branch name `master` to that commit."  So you have a whole *repository* containing files that have no slashes in their names, that you will need to clone separately into a folder *you* make.  You will have to repeat this for each Git repository.

My interpretation seems to conflict with your question though:

> But also I want to create new branch which contains the only "complete" folder as a root folder of this branch and push it as separate branch of my repository.  [How can I do that?]

This question implies that you created, not two separate repositories, but one single repository, in which you stored files named `complete/file1` *and* `starter/file2`, or files named `project/complete/file1` and `project/starter/file2`.  In this case you just have *one* repository to clone and check out.

Depending on which interpretation is correct, you might already have what you want, and might look into Git's so-called *submodules* for collecting together separate repositories.  Or, you might not have what you want, and might look into using `git filter-branch` or `git filter-repo` (or the poorly-maintained `git subtree`, but I would avoid this myself) to make a new repository containing fewer files, perhaps with altered names.

Note that a Git repository is forbidden from containing another Git repository.  Attempting to add a repository to a repository results in Git producing what I usually call a "half-assed submodule" (you need to use `git submodule add`, or a long series of extra commands, to make a "fully assed" submodule).  The `git add` command will print a warning message about these half-assed submodules; do not ignore it.

Comment: Yes, I admit that my question may be unclear at some point.
Better I show you which approach I already tried to use.

https://github.com/DevilDoctor27/NTF-preview-card

Here I have two branches and result is satisfying.
But, my problem is I need to make too many steps and they are seems to be not very smart. 
It the case that this project is small I don't need to change it often. So I just create new repository. Push my completed code. Remove .git folder and do "git init" in my subfolder and then push it as separate branch. 

So I thought there is might be some better way to do it.

Comment: When you remove the `.git`, you're removing the *entire repository*. What's left is your working tree, which consists of files that *are not in the repository* at that point (they were copied out of it, but are separate at that point). So when you then run `git init` you're making a new, second repository, independent of the original repository. There's nothing inherently wrong with this, it's just that you get two repositories that cannot interact sensibly with each other.